# Trig Substitution with integrals can't figure it out.

Tags: integration, trigonometry

The question is to find the indefinite integral of:

$$\int {x^2\over(x^2+a^2)^{(3/2)}}\;{{\rm d}x}$$

if anyone can help me out that would be awesome! I went through a few steps but I get stuck. So I use trig substitution and make x = atanu and dx = asec^2(u)

$$\int {a^3tan^2(u)sec^2(u)\over(a^3sec^3(u))}\;{{\rm d}x}$$

which simplifies to:

$$\int {tan^2(u)\over(sec(u))}\;{{\rm d}x}$$

and now I'm stuck because I don't see what substitution. Guide me please!

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please consider updating your question with some information about what you have tried or where you are getting stuck. You will find people are much more willing to help if you do!

Comment: Write it out in terms of $\sin u$ and $\cos u$...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Use the substitution: 
$$x = a \tan(\theta)\implies dx = a\sec^2 (\theta)\, d\theta$$

and use the identity:

$$\tan^2(\theta) + 1= \sec^2(\theta).$$

Comment: I did that, its more steps on when I get stuck!

Answer (score 1):

Where you have left $$\frac{\tan^2u}{\sec u}=\frac{\sin^2u}{\cos u}=\frac{1-\cos^2u}{\cos u}=\sec u-\cos u$$

Now use [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_the_secant_function)

as $\displaystyle \tan u=\frac xa, u=\arctan \frac xa$

using [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values), $\displaystyle-\frac\pi2\le u\le \frac\pi2\implies \sec u>0\implies \sec u=+\sqrt{1+\tan^2u}$